# Xcode Project Navigator, Cannot access Project

Tags: xcode

I am struggling a lot with this. And I know that the answer is staring me in the face somewhere but no matter what I search or look up and try, nothing works.

[image]

My schemes are all pointing to my pod frameworks and I cannot select the project target, even if I try and add a new scheme or edit an old one.

[image]

My project navigator starts with a folder as shown above, and I have NO idea how to revert back to whatever I had done to get it like this.

If anyone has any suggestions please help.

I cannot access target build settings or project build settings, Is there a way to access them without going through the project navigator ?

I cannot build properly as shown from the schemes, is there an easy fix to this ? Have I somehow changed the target path to an incorrect file location? How to revert back ?
I'm stuck :(

UPDATE:

deleting the .xcworkspace file and reinstalling the podfile gives below error code.

````
```
RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.8/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:218:in `initialize_from_file'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.8/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:103:in `open'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:918:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:917:in `each'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:917:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:912:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:78:in `analyze'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `analyze'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `install!'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D+Unknown+object+version.&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6992 [closed] [16 comments]
   31 Jan 2019

 - - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Malformed version number string ) during validation.
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8240 [closed] [16 comments]
   12 hours ago

 - Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"inputFileListPaths"=>[], "outputFileListPaths"=>[]} for the 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase' isa
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7835 [closed] [46 comments]
   2 hours ago

and 44 more at:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D%20Unknown%20object%20version.&type=Issues&ut
````

Comment: Try to run `pod install` again, open the .xcworkspace file and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Problem still persists

Comment: Try to delete the .xcworkspace file before running `pod install`, it will be re-created after that.

Comment: deleting the .xcworkspace file gives error message in pod terminal on install.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: will post in question. it is very long

Comment: Try this solution out: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6992#issuecomment-345656686

Comment: @TamásSengel does not work. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
To my particularly specific problem, I had permission issues with the RUBYGEMS that is installed by default on all MAC devices. 
I was not able to rebase my project to its original state as I did not have "write privileges". I had to install homebrew and rbenv which allowed me to (after deleting my cocoapods out of the project entirely) rebase my project to its original state before whatever I had done to rebase the file target to something else.

After installing Homebrew and Rbenv I installed a newer version of RubyGem which gave me admin permissions on the new install. Then I reinstalled cocoapods to the project and VOILA. Problem solved.